# How to monitor 'bad' messages written to kafka topic with no schema

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb

I use Kafka Connect to take data from RabbitMQ into kafka topic. The data comes without schema so in order to associate schema I use ksql stream. On top of the stream I create a new topic that now has a defined schema. At the end I take the data to BQ database. My question is how do I monitor messages that have not passed the stream stage? in this way, do i support schema evolution? and if not, how can use the schema registry functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> use Kafka Connect to take data ... data comes without schema

I'm not familiar specifically with Rabbitmq connector, but if you use the Confluent converter classes that do use schemas, then it would have one, although maybe only a string or bytes schema

---

If ksql is consuming the non-schema topic, then there's a consumer group associated with that process. You can monitor its lag to know how many messages have not yet been processed by ksql. If ksql is unable to parse a message because it's "bad", then I assume it's either skipped or the stream stops consuming completely; this is likely configurable

If you've set the output topic format to Avro, for example, then the schema will automatically be registered to the Registry. There will be no evolution until you modify the fields of the stream